# magento 2 How to get store Id phtml

Tags: magento2, store-id

I need to show something based on store id on Magento 2

for example;

```
<?php
$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
if ($storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() == 1):
?>
    <div class="block-bottom">
        <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" >
            <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            <span><?php echo __('Language'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="block-bottom">
        <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" >
            <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            <span><?php echo __('Language1'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Whats is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Hello @Gkna, if any answer solves your concern then mark as right, which will help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

**block file**

---

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }
    
    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

**.phtml file**

---

```
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
```

---

**you can use this in your `.phtml` file like this**

```
<?php if ($block->getStoreId() == 1): ?>
    <div class="block-bottom">
        <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" >
            <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            <span><?php echo __('Language'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="block-bottom">
        <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" >
            <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            <span><?php echo __('Language1'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Solution 2**

- (I don't recommend this but as per your comment)

> I need something easy

You can fetch the current store id and the store name in **phtml** file (using **ObjectManager**) like below

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

you can use this `$storeID` according to your condition :

```
if ($storeID > '1')
{
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: I used  it but it prints wrong variable. When i open store en (1) it shows  "Language1" I am trying to add the code in a header.phtml file, i dont have a block file. I think something is missing

Comment: create block file

Comment: In your module like this

Comment: your Vendor name\your Module name\Block;

Comment: Block file is compulsory

Comment: I need something easy

Comment: well You can fetch the current store id and the store name in phtml file

Comment: check my updated answer.